# How to mask XOR in UIImage

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimageview, image-masking

I want UIImage masking something like this as shown in the image below but using coregraphics masking, any answer is appreciated  [image]

Answer (score 2):

```
func maskImage(image:UIImage, mask:(UIImage))-> UIImage {

    let imageReference = image.cgImage

    let maskReference = mask.cgImage

    let imageMask = CGImage(maskWidth: maskReference!.width, height: maskReference!.height, bitsPerComponent: maskReference!.bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel: maskReference!.bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow: maskReference!.bytesPerRow, provider: maskReference!.dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true)

    let maskedReference = imageReference!.masking(imageMask!)

    let maskedImage = UIImage(cgImage:maskedReference!)

    return maskedImage

}
```

Comment: when i am giving source image as square and making image as circle then it is returning circle . where as it has to return the left part of the square which is not occupied by circle

Comment: It help me but I need exact reverse of it , can you help me in that ...?